# Laravel - How to change FCM default notification tune

Tags: php, laravel, firebase-cloud-messaging

this question was asked before and was ignored, if you have a solution for it then your contribution is valuable, is there any way to change the default sound of the FCM notification if I'm using the below code, changing "sound"=>"arrive" to soundtrack path is not working?
thank you

```
public function toFcm($notifiable) {
    $message = new FcmMessage();
    $notification = [
        'body' => trans('lang.notification_your_order', ['parcel_id' => $this->parcel->id, 'order_status' => $this->parcel->parcelStatus->status]),
        'image' => Config::get('app.url').'/uploads/parcel.png',
        'icon' => Config::get('app.url').'/uploads/parcel.png',
        "title" => "Order Updated",   
        "content_available" => true,
        "priority" => "high",
        "sound"=>"arrive",
        'id' => 'orders',
    ];
    $data = [
        'click_action' => "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
        'id' => 'orders',
        'status' => 'done',
        'message' => $notification,
    ];
    $message->content($notification)->data($data)->priority(FcmMessage::PRIORITY_HIGH);
    return $message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the name of the sound matches the name of the sound installed inside the **`res/raw`** folder, then ensure your request is correctly formatted

example: "filename.mp3"

```
{
  "token": "client_notification_token", <- or topic
  "notification": {
    "title": "Push notification title",
    "body": "Push body",
    "sound": "filename", <-- points to src/res/raw/filename.mp3
  }
  ...
}
```

Source: https://medium.flatstack.com/migrate-to-api-26-push-notifications-with-custom-sound-vibration-light-14846ebc9e96

Comment: so this needs also to work on the app? I don't have experience on dealing with the app but I can work from flutter also my app is done by a beginner developer on flutter

Comment: if you don't you wouldn't know what sound to play, FCM doesn't send a sound file every time, only the name to play.

Comment: so is there any way to do this? I already added the mp3 file in android->app->src->main->res->raw->sound.mp3 but when I push fcm and put the name file only the default sound were played